# Could not load file or assembly after installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, .net-assembly, setup-wizard

I encountered this error:

> ************** Exception Text **************
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Google.Apis.Core, Version=1.58.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Google.Apis.Core,
> Version=1.58.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'
> at DataManager.Form2.Form2_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
> IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
> failure logging, set the registry value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
> is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
> logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

This exception happens only when I build the application an install it with Setup wizard.
Then I get another error like this but with the "Google.Apis.Auth".
I don't know if it can cause this error but I load the program on multiple threads. Because of this, sometimes the SQlite does not have time to open the connection with the db. So I don't know if it just can't load these dlls.

And I also have some warnings like this:

> Warning       The explicit binding redirect on "Google.Apis.Core,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" conflicts with an
> autogenerated binding redirect. Consider removing it from the
> application configuration file or disabling autogenerated binding
> redirects. The build will replace it with: "". DataManager

I hope if someone could help me avoiding this error in the future.
Let me know If you need additional information!
Thanks!

update:
I tried turning off "Auto-generate binding redirects" but it's still not working properly!

Answer (score 1):

Okay now I managed to make it work by deleting the highlighted references from
Project>references (Auto-generate binding redirects is still off)

I rebuilt the project with the deleted references now it looks okay now.

I still welcome answers that can describe what caused and how can I avoid these kind of problems in the future!